# SVG Polygon transition

Tags: javascript, svg, css-transitions

I'm trying make a transition of SVG `<polygon>` element.

The codepen is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLQOKr

I have a polygon like this:

`<svg width="300" height="200" viewBox="0 0 300 200">
  <polygon points="0 0, 145 0, 150 20, 155 0, 300 0, 300 200, 0 200, 0 0" />
</svg>`

Now, when I change the value of `points` attribute, I can see the change reflected in the browser.

My goal here is to use the transition (e.g. `transition: all 2s ease 0s`) to see the animation of this change.

Is this doable in any way?

It the attached codepen, when you click the button, the `points` value is being replaced but the `transition` animation doesn't work.

Thanks,
Karol

Answer (score 3):

You can only use CSS animation on attributes that are designated as CSS "properties".  `points` is not one of those - at least not yet.

You can however animate it with the SMIL animation features of SVG.

```html
<svg width="300" height="200" viewBox="0 0 300 200">
  <polygon points="">
    <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="points"
             dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"
             values="0 0, 145 0, 150 20, 155 0, 300 0, 300 200, 0 200, 0 0;
                     0 0, 145 0, 150 50, 155 0, 300 0, 300 200, 0 200, 0 0;
                     0 0, 145 0, 150 20, 155 0, 300 0, 300 200, 0 200, 0 0"
             keyTimes="0; 0.5; 1" 
             calcMode="spline"
             keySplines=".5 0 .5 1;
                         .5 0 .5 1" />
  </polygon>
</svg>
```

Here we are specifying three keyframes: the start, the end, and then back to the start.  For the easing, there are two `keySplines` values, one for each direction of travel.

**Manual triggering**

If you need to be able to manually control the animation - such as per your example.  You can have two different `<animate>` elements. One for each direction. Then you can trigger each animation by calling `beginElement()`. You can find out more about that [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#InterfaceElementTimeControl).

**IE support**

Unfortunately, SMIL animation does not work in IE. So you would need to use the [FakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) JS library to add support to IE.

Or you could use one of the JS SVG libraries, like SNapJS, RaphaelJS etc.  Most of them have cross-browser animation functions.

**Or do the animation yourself :)**

Or, of course,  you could just do the interpolation of the path yourself.  Instead of setting that Y coord to either 20 or 50, use a timeout or `requestAnimationFrame` to change it in steps.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend SMIL as it has limited support and going to be deprecated in the nearest future. CSS animation won't work an attributes, so JS is the only way. Here's an example:

```js
var getPoints = function (isDeeper) {
    return isDeeper ?
        '0 0,  45 0, 150 150, 255 0, 300 0, 300 200, 0 200, 0 0' :
        '0 0, 145 0, 150  20, 155 0, 300 0, 300 200, 0 200, 0 0';
        
};

var pointsToObj = function (points) {
    var ps = points.match(/\d+/g).map(Number),
        obj = {length: ps.length};

    ps.forEach(function (n, i) {
        obj['_' + i] = n;
    });

    return obj;
};

var objToPoints = function (obj) {
    var ps = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
        ps.push(obj['_' + i]);

    return ps.join(' ');
};


var renderPoints = function ($element, isDeeper) {
    var dest = pointsToObj(getPoints(isDeeper)),
        src = pointsToObj($element.attr('points'));

    $(src).animate(dest, {
        step: function (now, fx) {
            src[fx.prop] = fx.now;
            $element.attr('points', objToPoints(src));
        }
    });
};

$(function () {

    var $button = $('button');
    var $element = $('svg polygon');
    var isDeeper = false;
    $button.bind('click', function () {
        isDeeper = !isDeeper;
        renderPoints($element, isDeeper);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg width="300" height="200" viewBox="0 0 300 200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <polygon points="0 0, 145 0, 150 20, 155 0, 300 0, 300 200, 0 200, 0 0"/>
</svg>

<button style="position:fixed;top:0;right:0">Click to change</button>
```

Comment: with the update to SVG2, js animations of svg will have as limited support as SMIL has. (your example doesn't work on FF). Any link about the deprecation of SMIL ? (don't tell me about chrome's "it's too hard for us!")

Comment: It does actually work on FF, my bad, missed the button : / But still, any link about official deprecation ?